# applyEdits to FeatureLayer does not add geometry

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, dojo

I'm trying to add the feature into the layer with a geometry type polygon. When I call applyEdits it adds the feature attributes into the layer but not its geometry.
Here is my dummy data object which is inserted into layer

```
[{
    "geometry": {
        "rings": [[[-16697923.619018555, 103676511.13576749], [-16697923.619018555, 103676511.13576749], [-16697923.619018555, 103676511.13576749], [-15584728.71105957, 103676511.13576749], [-16697923.619018555, 103676511.13576749]], [[-14582853.293945312, 103676511.13576749], [-15584728.71105957, 103676511.13576749], [-15362089.729492188, 103676511.13576749], [-14582853.293945312, 103676511.13576749]], [[-14248894.821533203, 103676511.13576749], [-14360214.31237793, 103676511.13576749], [-13247019.404418945, 103676511.13576749], [-14248894.821533203, 103676511.13576749]], [[-17922438.017700195, 103676511.13576749], [-17699799.036132812, 103676511.13576749], [-16697923.619018555, 103676511.13576749], [-17922438.017700195, 103676511.13576749]], [[-12245143.987304688, 103676511.13576749], [-13358338.895141602, 103676511.13576749], [-13024380.422851562, 103676511.13576749], [-12245143.987304688, 103676511.13576749]], [[-11911185.514892578, 103676511.13576749], [-12022505.005737305, 103676511.13576749], [-10909310.09777832, 103676511.13576749], [-11911185.514892578, 103676511.13576749]], [[-9907434.680664062, 103676511.13576749], [-11020629.588500977, 103676511.13576749], [-10686671.116210938, 103676511.13576749], [-9907434.680664062, 103676511.13576749]], [[-9796115.189819336, 103676511.13576749], [-9684795.69897461, 103676511.13576749], [-8607223.028198242, 103676511.13576749], [-8571600.791137695, 103676511.13576749], [-7569725.373901367, 103676511.13576749], [-8682920.281860352, 103676511.13576749], [-8610785.251831055, 103676511.13576749], [-9796115.189819336, 103676511.13576749]], [[-7347086.392333984, 103676511.13576749], [-7347086.392333984, 103676511.13576749], [-6233891.484375, 103676511.13576749], [-7347086.392333984, 103676511.13576749]], [[-5454655.048828125, 103676511.13576749], [-6233891.484375, 103676511.13576749], [-5120696.576538086, 103676511.13576749], [-5454655.048828125, 103676511.13576749]]],
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 102100
        }
    },
    "attributes": {
        ..
        ..
        ..
    }
}]
```

Here is the code

```
//Creating geometry from features collection
var features = [];
for (var i = 0; i < geojson.features.length; i++) {
    var geometry = geojson.features[i].geometry;
    if (geometry.type == "Polygon") {
        var feature = new Polygon(new SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
        var ring = []
        for (var j = 0; j < geometry.rings.length; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < geometry.rings[j].length; k++) {
                var ringPoint = [];
                ringPoint.push(geometry.rings[j][k][0]);
                ringPoint.push(geometry.rings[j][k][1]);
                //rings.push(ring);
                ring.push(ringPoint);
            }
        }
        feature.addRing(ring);
        //polygon.addRing(ring);
        //geometries.push(polygon);
        features.push(feature);
    }
}
var polygon = geometryEngine.union(features);
var geom = webMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(polygon);              
//Creating add feature                  
var editFeature = new Graphic({
    geometry: geom,
    attributes: attributes
});
lyr.applyEdits([editFeature], null, null, lang.hitch(this, function (results) {
    if (!results[0].success) {

    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a problem with the references systems.

The data you are showing is Web Mercator (wkid 102100 or 3587), but you are creating the polygons using geographic coordinates (wkid 4326), which are not. I think it should be,

```
var feature = new Polygon(new SpatialReference({ wkid: 102100 }));
```

Comment: I have tried adding `new SpatialReference({ wkid: 102100, latestWkid: 3857  })` but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you comment or delete the line that do the transformation using `geographicTo WebMercator`?, it is not need it .. Is the final geometry, after `union`, good?